# Initializing ivars in Java

Tags: java, instance-variables, getter-setter

Is there a difference or preferred preference between declaring and setting the default `ivars` like so:

```
public class Foo
{
   private int yes = 0;
   private String name = "";

   //...
   //constructors, setters, getters, etc.
}
```

---

```
public class Foo
    {
       private int yes;
       private String name;

       public Foo()
       {
          yes = 0;
          name = "";
       }
       //...
       //setters, getters, etc.
    }
```

Also, in `constructors` and other methods in `Foo` should I be setting and getting the `ivars` with the `accessor` and `mutator` methods or with simply assigning them directly?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't scatter the initializations -- keep them all together, to the extent that it's practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primitive types (`int` in your case) are initialized by default values automatically, so there  no reason to explicitly set it to `0`;

What about `Strings` and other objects: it's completely depends on your preferences. I prefer *not* to initialize it  in constructor. But keep in mind that in case of initilizing fields in constructor you can handle exceptions if field initializing throws some exception

Answer (score 0):

Same thing. Accessor and mutators methods will be needed for external classes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter and it's basically personal preference. Java compiler copies the initialization from a class to every constructor (no extra calls, it's really a direct copy in the bytecode).

Personally, I prefer to put the data-independent initialization to the class while I put the data that might depend on the constructor parameters to the constructor itself.